# VB.Net and Outlook Add-in - "Send & Receive All" event handler

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook

My question is about Visual Studio 2015, VB.Net with .Net 4.5, Outlook 2010 and "add in" development.

I want to handle the event when a user clicks the "Send & Receive All" button.

I can handle the event on a simple "Send Mail" click in the mail window message (`Application_ItemSend(...)`) but I don't know how to handle the event where "Send & Receive All" is clicked by a user.

I want it to work the same way as in [this commercial plug-in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWK1M8HeMYM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop though all SyncObject objects in the `Namespace.SyncObjects` collection and trap the `SyncStart` / `SyncEnd` events.

Comment: The code like this: Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core

Public Class test
`
    Dim WithEvents ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim WithEvents sy As Outlook.SyncObject

    Private Sub sy_SyncStart() Handles sy.SyncStart
 msgbox("Test 1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub sy_SyncEnd() Handles sy.SyncEnd
 msgbox("Test 2")
    End Sub

end Class`

Comment: Hi, ok to use SyncObjects NameSpace with `Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` but How to handle an email in the sending folder to sent it manually?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking - wouldn't Application.ItemSend work for that?

Comment: Not exactly, but my problem has evolved.
<br>
No problem to send a simple email when the user clicks "Send" in the Compose window of a new email, the event is triggered Application_SentItem, i catch it and send my modified email.
<br>
If a user wrote several mails but do not send them, they are stoqués in the "Drafts" folder. And then, at some point, he decided to send all the messages by clicking on the "Send and receive" button.

Comment: <br>
But clicking on then "Send and Receive" button, the defaut action of Outlook is that nothing happened. I can intercept a user action on this button performs actions of my add-in, but impossible to tell him to treat the rest of the messages that I do not deal.<br>

Comment: Draft messages saved in the Drafts folder are never automatically sent when you click Send/Receive. The user must explicitly click the Send button to send them.

Comment: Yes, of course ... Thank you thank you for reminding me that :-]